# Vuetify Calendar has no color or styles

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I just did a clean installation of Vue2+Vuetify - no issues.
I added an example Calendar from the Vuetify site as a component.
Then added the component in place of 'HelloWorld' in Home.vue
The resulting calendar has no color and some the drop-down menus are the width of the browser.
I expect I'm missing a CSS or something - but I'm out of guesses.
I would add the CSS and Icons CDN, but it's unclear how I do that in App.vue.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: Could you please outline exactly what steps you took during setting up your project so people can attempt to duplicate the process. Show commands executed and code changes you made

Comment: It's very telling how terrible the Vuetify documentation is by how many [tag:vuetify.js] questions there are on StackOverflow. You've probably just missed some critical step

Comment: I didn't respond though. I asked you to clarify your question. Do you think you could do that by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63893607/edit) to include the required details?

Comment: I walked through the stepped on an different laptop - - and it works! :)
So - this one is on me - I'll figure what's different between the two laptops!

Comment: Sometimes packages don't install correctly. Try `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your trying to use vuetify. I recommend when creating a vuetify project,
you should use `vue add vuetify`

so after running `vue create <project-name>`

you should run `vue add vuetify`

this will automatically configures the plugin for you. so that you can easily use the vuetify.

another thing is your components and stough. should be inside

```
<v-app>
     <!-- All Your elemts, router-view's and components should be inside here-->
<v-app>
```